# CSS: Floating DIV content spilling outside of container when using min-width. Rather have scrollers

Tags: css, width, scroller

hoping one of your guys would know the answer to this.

I have 2 floating DIVS and one DIV containers content that has min-width. When I resize window and window is smaller than min-width content, the content spills out of the parent container.

I would like parent container to expand to accomodate rather than have inside min-content to spill out and simply get horizontal scrollers at bottom of browser.

Anyone know solution?

```
<html>
    <style>
        .outer {
            width:100%;
            border:2px solid green;
            position:relative;
        }
        .left {
            float:left;
            width:20%;
            max-width:250px;
            background:red;
        }
        .right {
            float:left;
            width:80%;
            background:#eee;
        }
        .inner {
            min-width:620px;
            border:1px solid blue;
        }
        .clear {
            clear:both;
        }
    </style>
    <div class='outer'>
        <div class='left'>This is an inner content page. This is an inner content page.This is an
            inner content page.This is an inner content page.This is an inner content
            page.This is an inner content page.This is an inner content page.This is
            an inner content page.This is an inner content page.This is an inner content
            page.This is an inner content page.This is an inner content page.</div>
        <div
        class='right'>
            <div class='inner' class='clear'>This is an inner content page. This is an inner content page.This is an
                inner content page.This is an inner content page.This is an inner content
                page.This is an inner content page.This is an inner content page.This is
                an inner content page.This is an inner content page.This is an inner content
                page.This is an inner content page.This is an inner content page.</div>
            <div class='inner' class='clear'>This is an inner content page. This is an inner content page.This is an
                inner content page.This is an inner content page.This is an inner content
                page.This is an inner content page.This is an inner content page.This is
                an inner content page.This is an inner content page.This is an inner content
                page.This is an inner content page.This is an inner content page.</div>
    </div>
    <div style='clear:both'></div>
    </div>
```

Would like scrollers to appear horizontally on browser window (and not DIV) as it expands.

Comment: Where do you want a scrollbar to appear? You could make one appear with, for example, `overflow: auto` on `.outer`, but somehow I doubt that's quite what you wanted.

Comment: I would like the scroller to appear at bottom of browser and not as overflow of the right parent div.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the width on the top most parent to 100%. It will not grow larger than it's parent, which is the `body` in this case. If you want to make the `.outer` element larger you can specify a fixed width, http://jsfiddle.net/ETcf2/.

With that and the `min-width` removed the floated elements behave as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
.outer {
    width:100%;
    border:2px solid green;
    position:relative;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Anyway to make scroll appear at the bottom of browser vs as part of DIV? because content can be long and if scroll is part of DIV, user might not see it if content requires scrolling down to see horizontal scroller.